# Rails Testing Table not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, has-many

So I'm trying to figure out how to test the has_many relationship but I'm having some difficulties.

Here's the error

```
table tokens has no column named user_id
```

Here's how I recreated the error

```
$ rails new lab
$ cd lab
$ rails g model user name  # has_many tokens
$ rails g model token code # belongs_to user
$ rake db:migrate

# tokens.yml
one:
  code: 0A
  user: user_one
two:
  code: 0B
  user: user_one

# users.yml
  user_one:
  name: John

# user_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "has tokens" do
    user = users(:user_one)
    assert_not_equal [], user.tokens
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **1-M relationship** between `User` and `Token`, `tokens` table must have foreign_key to `users` table. You forgot to create that.
In your test case you are calling `user.tokens` but as `tokens` table doesn't have a foreign key named `user_id`, you get the error as

`table tokens has no column named user_id`

To resolve this,

Generate a migration to add the column `user_id` as foreign key in `tokens` table by running following command:

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToTokens user:references
```

After this run `rake db:migrate` to migrate the changes in `tokens` table.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your db/schema.rb, you will notice that there is no column named user_id in the tokens table. But in your fixtures, you reference user_one as if it should. If you modify your rails generator command to `rails g model token code:string user_id:int` then it should work.